# Set migrate:safe to user defined table in waterline

Tags: waterline, node-mysql

I have to create user defined tables in waterline though custom query method(.query()).

```
custom.con.query("CREATE TABLE "+req.body.table_name+",function(err,model){});
```

After that i have  to create coloumns in this table again through custom query.

```
custom.con.query("ALTER TABLE "+req.body.table_name+" ADD "+req.body.coloumn_name,function(err,model){});
```

Problem is once table is created and it's coloumns also created.but when i restart server coloumns in table vanish.

In other waterline models i can handle this problem by setting value of migrate:"safe".

Is there any way to set such configuration in custom tables.???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user786, it seems that you have your default `migrate` setting set to `'alter'` or `'drop'`. You can change this by adding a `defaults` object to your waterline initialisation, example:

```
var config = {
  // adapters
  // models
  // etc...

  defaults: {
    // will apply to any model that doesn't have a 'migrate' definition
    migrate: 'safe'
  }
};

waterline.initialize(config, function(err, models) {
  console.log("waterline initialised.");
});
```

Code example in [waterline examples](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/example/express/express-example.js#L52-L54).

The non-destructive options are `'safe'` and `'create'`, more details in the [adapter specification docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/contributing/adapter-specification.md#auto-migration-strategies) and in [sails model settings](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html?q=migrate).

Comment: Oh yeah my bad i set migrate alter in config/model.js while in all model files it was migrate:safe ....thanx alot